# Create Excel worksheet by filtering another worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have a worksheet with the following values
[image]
I want to, using an equation if possible, rearrange these values into three columns, in another worksheet, based on whether they are low, medium or high risk, like so

[image]

Pay no attention to the coloring and borders, I can add that later (or use conditional formatting).

**Questions:** could someone provide either a minimal working example (MWE) or the equation to use to make convert one table into three side by side tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use VBA to solve this issue:

```
Sub Sortdata()

Dim wsRisk As Worksheet, wsThisSheet As Worksheet
Dim colHigh As Long, colMed As Long, ColLow As Long

colHigh = 3
colMed = 3
ColLow = 3

Set wsThisSheet = ActiveSheet

With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "Risk"
End With

Set wsRisk = Worksheets("Risk")
wsRisk.Range("A1").Value = "Risk of Responsibility"
wsRisk.Range("A2").Value = "High Risk"
wsRisk.Range("C2").Value = "Medium Risk"
wsRisk.Range("E2").Value = "Low Risk"

lastrow = wsThisSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To lastrow
    If wsThisSheet.Cells(x, 4).Value = "High" Then
    wsRisk.Range("A" & colHigh & ":B" & colHigh).Value = wsThisSheet.Range("B" & x & ":C" & x).Value
    colHigh = colHigh + 1
    ElseIf wsThisSheet.Cells(x, 4).Value = "Med" Then
    wsRisk.Range("C" & colMed & ":D" & colMed).Value = wsThisSheet.Range("B" & x & ":C" & x).Value
    colMed = colMed + 1
    ElseIf wsThisSheet.Cells(x, 4).Value = "Low" Then
    wsRisk.Range("E" & ColLow & ":F" & ColLow).Value = wsThisSheet.Range("B" & x & ":C" & x).Value
    ColLow = ColLow + 1
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```